Should I use required modifier with Entity Framework navigations?
Nullable Reference Types is enabled.
public class TestExecution
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ParametersSet? ParametersSet { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Environment")]
    public required int EnvironmentId { get; set; }

    public required Environment Environment { get; set; }
}

public class ParametersSet
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    [ForeignKey("TestExecutionId")]
    public int TestExecutionId { get; set; }

    public TestExecution TestExecution { get; set; }
}

public class Environment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public ICollection<TestExecution> TestExecutions { get; set; } = new List<TestExecution>();
}

I understand that I shouldn't use required with an optional (nullable-since NRT is enabled) relationship. Hence, why I wrote public ParametersSet? ParametersSet { get; set; } in TestExecution.
However, from dependent parametersSet to principal TestExecution, should I use required like so:
public class ParametersSet
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TestExecutionId")]
    public required int TestExecutionId { get; set; }

    public required TestExecution TestExecution { get; set; }
}

Or like so from dependent entity TestExecution to principal entity Environment?
public class TestExecution
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ParametersSet? ParametersSet { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Environment")]
    public required int EnvironmentId { get; set; }

    public required Environment Environment { get; set; }
}

EF docs suggest using required with reference types but it's not explicit whether to do so with navigations or not.

It seems to me the documentation is suggesting using required navigation properties but goes into a discussion of whether these should be nullable or not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#required-navigation-properties

To me this is another example of C# going off the rails. Now we have required attributes, required keywords, required members that may be null, required members that may be nullable or non-nullable. It seems like required gives you very little real information and only makes it confusing should you use it or not or something else. Maybe its meant for compiler tricks? No idea.

@topsail, I think in that page you referenced, they're talking about whether the relationship itself is required or not. Hence, why they're talking about NRT. The page I linked to in my question is the one mentioning using required modifier.

I disagree, I think they are talking about the member being required (use of the required modifier), not whether a relationship itself is required - i.e., it is is just continuing the discussion from the previous paragraph, now in regard to navigation properties. I know this is not clear, which is why I made the comment. I may be wrong. I don't precisely understand what you mean by "a relationship being required" - what would that even mean?

In that section you referenced they didn't even mention the word "modifier" or "keyword". But anyways, it's not the point. Here's what a "required relationship" means from the docs.

FYI, required modifier only controls property initialization. So, you can have required but initialize it to null hence the relationship is not required. So, that's why I'm saying that section in the docs you are referring to is not about the required modifier.

For entity navigation properties I personally don't. Even with NRT my preference is to use DDD-style constructors, private setters, and actions to update the domain in predictable & complete passes. Of course the compiler complains if non-nullable references aren't initialized, and EF wants a default constructor when navigation properties are involved, so the lesser evil is a protected default constructor marked to ignore the compiler warning around NRT. The code is "safe" enough from invalid state without getting stupid & circle-jerked through hoops.

@noobie well if you are trying to use the required keyword to represent "required relationships" I think you have answered your own question.

@topsail, no I'm not trying to represent required relationships using required modifier. I was just wondering if I should use it to enforce anything that would make the code more durable or maintainable.
